# Function to use with multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I have modified a function to meet my need. This is what I have written to restrict multiple repetition of dots:

```
$('#title').val(){
    replace(/\.{2,}/g, '.');
});
```

Is it correct? How can I make this in function so I can call with every element of the form?

Comment: [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/5Yk74/)?

Comment: Exactly, and If I want to add two conditions than? I mean I wanna do it for dots and hyphen at same time.

Comment: I will write that for you and I will post it as an answer.

Comment: I mean I want to add more than 10 replacing conditions...

Comment: Sure...I will acccept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Here is your code turned into a jQuery function/plugin.

```
jQuery.fn.singleDotHyphen = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.val(function(){
            return $this.val()
                .replace(/\.{2,}/g, '.')
                .replace(/-{2,}/g, '-');    
        });
    });
}
```

#### 2. Here is how you use it

```
$('selector').singleDotHyphen();
```

#### 3. [Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/5Yk74/)

Comment: I saved this function in another file named as `clean.js` in my particular file I am calling this function but its returning same instead of result. 

**function () {    return $this.val().replace(/\.{2,}/g, ".").replace(/-{2,}/g, "-");}**

Comment: As I use it on keypress. It restrict me type further.

Comment: @RahulSingh [Here is how to do it with keypress](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/czc2f/). If you want the function to be on a separate file, you have to move the whole jQuery function/plugin in it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work -

```
$('input[type=text],textarea').blur(function () {
    $(this).val(function () {
        return $(this).val().replace(/\.{2,}/g, '.');
    });
});
```

That would apply your RegEx to every 'text' or 'texarea' input field once it lost focus. Here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/xcBFx/1/

Comment: This is not a jQuery function.

Comment: It's not a plug-in. I didn't think the OP was specifically asking for a plug-in just for their code to be refactored so it worked with multiple form elements.

Comment: _"how can I make this in function so I can call with every element of form"_ That should explain it all. :)

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I think 'this in function' would apply to both our answers. Obviously the OP didn't think that as he accepted your answer and ignored mine :) I'm going to stubbornly stick to my guns for the moment though, I might delete the answer later.